# jquery: how to select element from innerHTML?

Tags: jquery

I have to autocomplete for a textbox within an innerHTML(this innerHTML is loaded by AJAX)
, normally if we use `$("#elementid").autopopulate` will work if `elementid` is within in an html content, but it will not work for if `elementid` is within an innerHTML in the same page. When i checked with Firebug, the AJAX call is not fired when we enter a character?
     The problem is with the selection, i guess, so I need to know how to select an element within an innerHTML?

thanks in advance.

---

I need one more help..after the user selecting the autocompleted value from the list in textbox, i need to do some operation on the same and get printed the resulted value  on another textbox, how will i achieve this?

---

see jquery code below for calling elt in innerhtml

$(function(){ $("input[name='item_no']").autocomplete("auto/finditem.cfm"); })

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

In those cases there is Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rgkQK/

I made up an example of your code. I hope this will help.

If I get you right you want to select a child element from a parent element.

You have to use the following jQuery selector

```
jQuery('parent > child')
```

Documentation at:
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: thanks for the reply......
so can I use in this way $("divid textid")

where my html is as follows, and div content is generated by ajax
<div id="divid" name="divid">
        <input type="text" id="textid" name="textid">
</div>

thanks

Comment: if u r trying to acces value from the textbox #textid u shud be using $("input[name='textid']").val();

Comment: hi manraj,
    see the call <script>
$(function(){  

$("input[name='item_no']").autocomplete("auto/finditem.cfm");
})
</script>

but still its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try calling $("#textid").autocomplete("auto/finditem.cfm"); in the ajax request's success-function